# Web Browser rendering

Tags: web, browser, graphics, gpu, cpu

I am currently researching how the web browser works to render different frames and in-browser animations. Although there is a lot of information available on the Internet, none of the resources available seem to be suitable to answer my questions so any help would be greatly appreciated. 
These are my questions:

1) First of all, is the browser refresh rate dependent on the monitor refresh rate? (does browser refresh rate = monitor refresh rate?)

2) What is the role of the GPU, CPU and Memory in rendering web page frames? Are frames rendered by the CPU or the GPU?

3) Does there exist some sort of V-Sync capability for web browsers?

Thank you

Comment: 1) Yes, see `requestAnimationFrame` on MDN. 2) WebKit can use layers that are rendered in the GPU 3) There is no tearing in a browser, JS is run-to-completion and CSS transitions state is changed after each frame, not in the middle of a frame. No V-sync needed. V-sync is needed for games, where tearing could appear. You shouldn't need it but if that's the case, use WebGL.